# How to check the table has value using Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a table.and I need to check the table has at-least one value.and if the text in the table named Test set some alert

my table structure is

```
<table id="chk-table">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Check 
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Test
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Check1
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I tried something tlke

```
if ($('#chk-table tr').length >0) {
            if ($('#chk-table td:contains("Unknown")')) {
                alert("Test");
            }
        }
```

but when the table has no value the alert is showing
Can anyone help?

Comment: By values do you mean text? Because the way you're doing it will alert as long as there's a <tr> tag, even if there's no text within it. You should try if ($("#chk-table tr").text() != "") {

Comment: @Coh3n yes I mean text

Comment: How do you determine/identify (valid) values?

Comment: what is #body_ctl99_lstWasteMaterial ?

Comment: @Arun I mean which element has the id "body_ctl99_lstWasteMaterial" ??

Comment: @AnoopJoshi I just edited the question please have a look.

Comment: A jQuery selector (`$('#chk-table td:contains("Unknown")')`) *always* returns a jQuery object; because it returns an object this is a 'truthy' value therefore the `if` assessment *always* evaluates to `true`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a `.length` on the end of your selector if you are testing if it exists:

```
if ($('#chk-table td:contains("Unknown")').length) {
    alert("Test");
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/fNT32/)

Comment: if the given string match any where it will be matched

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
if ($('#chk-table tr').text().trim() != "") {
    alert("Test");
}
```

That should alert if there is any text in any of the table's `<tr>` tags.

Comment: it would be better if you use $('#chk-table tr').text().trim()